# Querying a MySQL database twice in two different functions within a class

Tags: php, mysql

I have an upload class built in PHP that has various functions for checking the file and making sure it meets the correct specifications. However I have a function that strips the name of the file and gives it a new name which is a number. In this function I include my connection include to start a connection with the DB. To prevent giving two files the same name I have table in my database that holds the current count which refers to the last image number. When I upload an image it pulls the count from the database and adds one to it and stores that number as the name for the image. I then update the table with the new count by querying the DB again. This works fine however when I query the database in another function to enter the path to the file it tells me that my connection variable isn't declared. I have posted the code for my connection include below as well as the two functions I am calling. I am curious if I am not starting the connection in the correct place. I have tried freeing the result and closing the connection after the function has been called and then opening the connection again in the other function to submit the file path but that didn't seem to work either. I know their is a rule about having one connection open at any one time but I though you could query the DB as many times as you want within that connection.

Connection include

```
// Create a database connection
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "new_db";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// Test if connection occured.
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() . 
        " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
}
```

First function

```
//replaces the filename with an incremented number
public function trim_filename() {
    require_once( 'includes/connection.php' );
    $query = "SELECT * FROM image_count ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed. ");
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count = 1 + $row["name"];
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    $query = "UPDATE image_count SET name = '{$count}' WHERE count = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed. ");
    }
    $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file = explode(".", $file);
    $file = end($file);
    $file = $count . "." . $file;
    $_FILES['image']['name'] = $file;
    $this->final_check();
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Second function

```
public function database_query($in_path) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO course (";
    $query .= " course_name ";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .= " '{$in_path}'";
    $query .= ")";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed. ");
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem, faced especially if you have prior experience using the old `mysql_query()` API, which relied on a connection resource plucked from a global state.  You need to get `$connection` in the proper scope to use it in your functions.

The best way to handle this is *not* to do the `require_once()` inside the class at all to establish the connection. Instead, perform that action *outside the class*, and pass the resulting `$connection` variable to the class' `__construct()` method.  Then store it in a property in the class, where you may use it as `$this->connection`.  This is called *dependency injection*.

```
class ThisClass
{
  // A public property for the connection
  protected $connection;

  // Modify your __construct() to accept the connection
  public function __construct(/* existing params... , */ mysqli $connection)
  {  
    // Whatever your constructor already does...
    // Store the connection in a property
    $this->connection = $connection; 
  }

  // Then modify those two methods to use $this->connection
  public function trim_filename() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM image_count ";
    // Use $this->connection
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed. ");
    }
    // SNIP....
    // Don't free/close the connection! 
  }
  // Then modify those two methods to use $this->connection
  public function database_query($in_path) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO course (";
    // SNIP...
    // Use $this->connection
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed. ");
    }
    // Don't free/close the connection!
  }
}
```

Now, to use your class with the connection dependency:

```
// Done outside the class, defines $connection
require_once( 'includes/connection.php' );
// Then when you use the class
// give it the $connection as a parameter
$object = new ThisClass($connection);
$object->trim_filename();
```

There isn't a *rule* about having one connection open at any time, but it is rare and somewhat exotic to *need* more than one.

A non-ideal alternative: If you *really* don't want to store the connection in a class property for some reason, you could alternatively modify both methods to accept `$connection` as a paramter like

```
// Add a param to the functions that need it.
public function trim_filename($connection) {
  // use $connection->query(...);
}
// Call outside the class as:
$object->trim_filename($connection);
```

where you still do the `require_once()` outside the class. But injecting it as a dependency into the constructor is cleaner, and offers you a simple path to expand more methods in the class requiring access to the database connection.

Accessing the `$connection` variable with a `global` keyword inside methods which need it is the *least desirable* method to use, especially if you continue to establish it inside one of the class functions.  By object oriented principles, it should not be the class' responsibility to establish database connections. Instead, if the class needs one, it should be passed to the object from outside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very well explain! Michael Berkowski

Answer (score -1):

Can you try "global connection;" in the database_query function ? also you shouldn't close the connection in the functions

```
public function database_query($in_path) {

   global $connection; 

   $query = "INSERT INTO course (";
   $query .= " course_name ";
   $query .= ") VALUES (";
   $query .= " '{$in_path}'";
   $query .= ")";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   if (!$result) {
       die("Database query failed. ");
   }
   mysqli_free_result($result);
   mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way handle these type of situation is 
Place all you function at one file like (example: function.php ) then include your connection.php file at top of the function.php.Use global variable to get you connection object in every function

Connection.php file

```
// Create a database connection
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "new_db";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// Test if connection occured.
 if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die("Database connection failed: " .
     mysqli_connect_error() . 
     " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
 );
}
```

function.php file

```
//inculing connnection.php file
require_once( 'includes/connection.php' );

//first funtion
public function trim_filename() {
    globel $connection;
    // code here
}   

//second funtion
public database_query($in_path) {
    globel $connection;
    // code here
}
```